# Visual Studio copy existing database into MVC project for offline development

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition for an ASP.NET MVC project which targets a database on an SQL Server 2012 instance.

I want to be able to continue development when not connected to the network so therefore need a copy of the database which I would have in my App_Data folder.

I have not come across a quick and easy solution to pull down a copy of the database into my project, which would include schema and data (the database I am working with is fairly small).

Is there anything already in Visual Studio which would allow me to take a copy and update when required? If not, what other methods are people using?

**EDIT:**

The full database engine is not installed locally, only the supporting applications SSMS, BIDS etc. The Express LocalDB versions are available as they were installed as part of the Visual Studio installation.

Comment: I'm assuming you have SQL Server installed locally? If so you can take a full backup of the database on the server and restore this on the local machine. I would do this with SQL Server Management Studio, you can get the express version here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=29062

Comment: Afraid not, only the Express LocalDB version as part of the Visual Studio installation - unless it would still work with this?